# Quick Access Toolbar icons won't go away

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

I made a Word Template some time ago.  Since then, it was renamed, removed, or replaced.

I had created buttons on the quick access toolbar for this template.  Those buttons are still there, but the original file that contained their macros is gone.  I can't get rid of those buttons.

When I right-click and select "customize quick access toolbar", they aren't there for me to remove.

When I hover over the button, it shows the pathway to where the file used to be, but it's not there anymore.

when I click on the button, I get an error stating:

```
"The macro cannot be found or has been disabled because of your macro security settings"
```

I have been searching for a solution for the last several hours.

Does anyone know how to get these buttons off of the quick access tool bar?

Comment: Under "Customize Quick Access Toolbar", there's a drop-down that allows you to select "For all documents (default)" or other active documents. Does selecting any of the other options change whether the buttons appear in the list?

Comment: No it doesn't.  I tried each one

Comment: My "best" guess is that I created the buttons,  then renamed the document as well as the Macros.   somehow the quick access toolbar buttons got stuck.  I have a template I am using now,  when I uncheck it as an addin, the buttons go away, but they are there again when I re-add the template.  I must have renamed this one I'm working on now.   Same issue though..  The macros don't exist and the buttons won't go away

Comment: I also have this issue !